# Can you force replace some functions in C with visual studio?

Tags: c, visual-studio

I created a c++/cli wrapper for a C library, now working on the feedback system.

The native library simply prints its feedback to the console window using functions like error(...) and info(...) that do the formatting and printing. Each of the library projects has a header "common.h" that among other things provides these functions.

I created my own static feedback library and functions that mimic the signature of these calls so they could be a drop-in replacement that work in conjunction with the cli dll and raise static events. I had success in including the library in one of the projects and after replacing all the original feedback calls with the names of my own it performed as expected.

It is my interest though to not modify the original libraries so I was wondering if there is a way to force the replacement of these calls with my own ones if built from the c++cli project? I did find an option to force the header of my library on all the projects, if there was something to also force exclude the original feedback header I'd be in business! Any ideas?

Comment: google for API hooking

Comment: Just write your own function with the exact same signature as the original.  The linker will use yours instead of importing the original from a static library.

Comment: that gives me linker error LNK2005 "_info already defined in libFeedback.lib" originating from common.obj

Comment: sounds like he wants to replace functions in already built code, so I think hooking or proxy dll is the only way

Comment: If you have the library sources, you just exclude files where the original feedback functions are defined from the project. Headers have nothing to do with it. Your own headers probably provide the exact same definitions as the original files.

Answer (score 0):

It is not immediately clear why writing the functions and including them in a .c file in the project doesn't work. Your version should be picked up by direct linkage (all .obj files are linked before any libraries).